# Is it possible to create a design like this using the Grid List in the Material UI?

Tags: material-ui

Is it possible to create a design like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRsZg.jpg) using the [GridList](https://material-ui.com/components/grid-list/) in the Material UI?

Please let me know if there are any possible remedies or ideas that may help solve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Grid 1 with 2 columns; in the 2nd column, have 2 rows of 2 columns each

Comment: @AkberIqbal
Thank you for your comment.
Is it possible to implement this using the GridList in the Material UI?